# Can you whitelist a single CA for a domain?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

Simply: For my domain (say example.com), I want my computer to only trust HTTPS certs signed by my personal CA, and ONLY my personal CA.

Otherwise any one of the CAs I have on my computer could create a valid cert for my personal domain and I would never notice.

I have heard of Name Constraints, but it seems to limit what each CA can do, not limit a computers trust for a domain to only a single CA. Are there any other ways that I can accomplish this restriction?

Comment: If you signed your domain with your own CA, what stops you from explicitly trusting the leaf CA? I don't really understand what you are trying to protect yourself against. Can you please [edit] your question and show what your threat model is?

Comment: @MechMK1 As I understand it, he wants to prevent other root CAs in his computer (ones used for the internet such as Verisign) from issuing certificates for his own site. So basically key pinning.

Comment: @PeterHarmann Ahh, now I understand the question. In this case, yes, HPKP would be the way to go, but it's so dangerous I would never want to try it.

Comment: @MechMK1 yeah, I don't know why I assumed we are talking about personal site, such as home server, but the question does not state that. I edited the answer to include a proper warning.

Comment: @PeterHarmann I assumed a personal site, because for a website intended to be seen by the general public, using a self-signed CA is not advisable at all. (I've seen some local gov't websites attempt to do this ~2005, but luckily even they understand that a publicly trusted CA is the way to go).

Comment: @MechMK1 well, ok not public but it may not be a home one. Even an office or school site etc would be tricky with HPKP. Also, I just realized support was dropped by Chrome, never adopted on IE and buggy/incomplete on Firefox, so probably better to just avoid it altogether.

Comment: There is no way to do that with a browser. With software you control, you can choose trusted CAs for each connection, but that's not what you want. Closest to what you want is DNS CAA, but it's not enforced by technical means so the amount of security you get from it is doubtful.

Comment: I still don't understand what the threat model is. Michael, what are you trying to protect yourself from?

Comment: Browsers trust hundreds of CAs that can be compromised and generate a cert for OP's domain. The current best defense is Certificate Transparency.

Comment: @MechMK1 , one possible example is a large organization that has a root CA, and multiple divisions, each with their own SCA issuing their own client certificates. Each division trusts all corporate certificates, but my servers contain PCI data, and I can’t trust the SCAs in marketing to not issue certificates in my name. I’d want to limit the trust only to client certificates issued by my SCA.

Comment: @MechMK1 it's 2020, and in Brazil a lot of government sites (our IRS, for example) requires you to install a custom CA to be allowed to access it...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Certification Authority Authorization (CAA) Record](https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/caa-record/) on your DNS zone.

It specifies the CAs you want to issue your certificates from. It can be more than one. And you can even have a special record with a mail address to report violations.

For example, take a look at those records:

```
example.com.  CAA 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"
example.com.  CAA 0 issuewild "comodoca.com"
example.com.  CAA 0 iodef "mailto:example@example.com"
```

In this example, LetsEncrypt can issue certificates for `example.com`, but not wildcard certificates. Only Comodo can issue wildcard certificates. And if someone else issues certificates for `example.com`, an email should be sent to `example@example.com`.

So if someone tries to issue a certificate for `example.com` at VeriSign, VeriSign would check the CAA record, see they aren't authorized to, and inform `example@example.com`. And [Certificate Transparency](https://www.certificate-transparency.org/) requires that CAs log all certificates they issue, so any third party can check the certificates on the log and the corresponding CAA Record on the domain to see if any CA issued a certificate when they should have not.

Answer (score 0):

Major browsers and operating systems don't support this.

You could try using [HPKP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Public_Key_Pinning), however **beware** that HPKP is **dangerous**, especially for public websites. It can achieve what you desire, but it is tricky to achieve and failing can completely block the domain for years. It will also work for (or block) all visitors, not just one PC.

EDIT: Support for HPKP was dropped by Chrome, which I did not realize when writing this, so probably just don't use it.

Comment: Unsurprising that support was dropped. You could buy a domain, enable HPKP for like 10 years, then resell the domain.